# JAXB: Validating XML Enum as String while preserving type in XSD

Tags: java, enums, jaxb

I have my transport class with annotations:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType
public class PersonalData {

  @XmlElement
  private ETSalutation salutation;

}
```

Generated XSD is nice:

```
<xs:element name="salutation" type="tns:ETSalutation"/>
```

Known fact is, that JAXB will set null, when in incoming XML an unknown value is found. I need to check it, so I would like to use an XmlAdapter to do my internal validation. But when I implement an adapter:

```
 class ETSalutationEnumAdapter implements XmlAdapter<String, ETSalutation>
```

and attach it:

```
  @XmlElement
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ETSalutationEnumAdapter.class)
  private ETSalutation salutation;
```

... I get in XSD a string type:

```
<xs:element name="salutation" type="xs:string"/>
```

When I force the type using @XmlElement(type = ETSalutation.class), then in Adapter I will get ClassCastException.

So, long story short: how can i preserve my Enum type in XSD and still be able to access the incoming raw string value of it?

Blaise? :)

Answer (score 1):

As no answers has been posted, here what I have done (dirty hack, but works...):
Gave up adapters, apparently they are not able to handle that.

I have introduced my own class 
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeEnumLeafInfoImpl

that **shadows** the original one. Class body is the same, with one change in parse(CharSequence lexical) method, which looks now like that:

```
@Override
public T parse(CharSequence lexical) throws AccessorException, SAXException {

    B b = this.baseXducer.parse(lexical);

    if (this.tokenStringType) {
        b = (B) ((String) b).trim();
    }

    T value = this.parseMap.get(b);

    // no value found, means incorrect value in incoming XML
    if (value == null) {
        // find out XML field name
        String fieldName = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(getUpstream().getLocation().toString(), ".");
        // add error data to context
        Triple error = Triple.of(getClazz(), fieldName, lexical.toString());
        // Context is my own class, which contains ThreadLocal field to gather all errors
        Context.getJaxbEnumErrors().add(error);
        LOG.debug("Enum parsing error: " + error);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Based on data from my Triple I can now match the place in XML for which I need to report error, and I have the invalid value :) But the solution is extremely dirty